# filter field width space django orm

Tags: python, django

I have a problem when doing a filter in a queryset since the field I want to filter with spaces and I can not modify the table that I consulted because it is an external table. I need do this:

```
array = ['456FG','432TT','234CC','678TT']
query = MyModel.objects.filter(clave__in=array)
```

however the values come like this 
`'456FG   '
 '432TT   ' 
 '234CC   ' 
 '678TT   '`

with spaces because if I use the __in it does not bring me results and I need it to be exact because I can not use __icontains. help

Comment: are there always three spaces following the value?

Comment: I am sorry but i am not clear some point. Dose you model field contains `space` ? or in your query array contain `space` ?

Comment: @Shakil I think OP is saying that the values in the database have the additional spaces appended

Comment: yes and I can not modify the value I only have permission to consult it and all values arrive with spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are always three spaces following the value you can just modify the query array to include the spaces like this:

```
array = ['456FG','432TT','234CC','678TT']
new_array = [a + '   ' for a in array]
query = MyModel.objects.filter(clave__in=new_array)
```

Comment: very well it seems that it has worked in this way :D